# Best way to find dependencies magento

Tags: module, magento-1, dependency

I just deactivate a custom module but magento is still looking for a file from that module and got this error:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: apc failed to locate Mage/Gomage/Navigation/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Category/Column.php - bailing  in /vagrant/shop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

#0 /vagrant/shop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include() [autoload('Mage_Gomage_Nav...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Mage_Gomage_Nav...')
#4 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1346): class_exists('Mage_Gomage_Nav...')
#5 /vagrant/shop/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('gomage_navigati...', Array)
#6 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(383): Mage::getModel('gomage_navigati...')
#7 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#8 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#9 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#10 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#13 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#15 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#16 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#17 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#18 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#19 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#20 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#21 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#22 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#23 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#24 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#25 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#26 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#27 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#28 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#29 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#30 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /vagrant/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /vagrant/shop/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}
```

i have been trying to find where is this module called in other place in the code to remove it but i cant find it, so what is the best way to search for this dependencies in magento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the stack:

```
#7 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#8 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#9 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#10 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
```

you can see that it happens in the category tabs when preparing the category attributes, so probably you need to delete an attribute from your database which uses a source model of the deleted module.
Have a look in the `eav_attribute` table and look in the column `source_model`.
There you will find a reference to gomage_navigation.

Edit: To speed this up, you can also look in the setup scripts of the deleted module which attributes it creates and then pinpoint the warrior of destruction ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have SSH access, search in your app directory:

```
grep -nr "Gomage_Navigation" *
```

or

```
grep -nr "gomage_navigation" *
```

Comment: grep can be used to find multitudes of sins <grin>. *nix is your friend on this type issue.